# Missing properties trying to patch state

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, ngxs

I am trying to decode an ssl certificate and patch the state of an array property. This is what I am doing now:

State Model

```
export interface CertificateStateModel {
  certificate: CertificateObject;
  certificates: Certificate[];
  searchLimitedStateMessage: string;
  emptyCertificateMessage: string;
  searchTerm: any;
}

@State<CertificateStateModel>({
  name: "certificate",
  defaults: {
    certificate: null,
    certificates: [],
    searchLimitedStateMessage: SearchMessages.typeToSearch,
    emptyCertificateMessage: SearchMessages.typeToSearch,
    searchTerm: null,
  },
})
```

function to decode cert

```
function decodeCert(CertificateObject) {
  if (CertificateObject)
  for (let entity of CertificateObject) {
    const certPem = atob(entity)
    console.log(entity)
          const cert = pki.certificateFromPem(certPem)
          const fingerprint = forge.md.sha1.create().update(forge.asn1.toDer(forge.pki.certificateToAsn1(cert)).getBytes()).digest().toHex();
          const currentDate = new Date();
          const daysToExpire = cert.validity.notAfter.valueOf() - currentDate.valueOf();

            let certificates = {
                name: entity.name,
                issueDate: cert.validity.notBefore,
                expiryDate: cert.validity.notAfter,
                fingerPrint: fingerprint,
                serialNumber: cert.serialNumber,
                daysToExpire: daysToExpire / 86400000,
            }
            return certificates;
        }
  }
```

Action to get certs and patch state:

```
@Action(CertificateAction.GetAllCertificates)
  getAllCertificates(
    ctx: StateContext<CertificateStateModel>,
    action: CertificateAction.GetAllCertificates
  ) {

    ctx.dispatch(new Busy(true));
    return this.svc.getAllCertificates().pipe(
      tap((certificate) => {
        ctx.patchState({
          certificate: decodeCert(certificate)
        });
        ctx.dispatch(new Busy(false));
        console.log(certificate)
      },
      (error: any) => {
        ctx.dispatch([
          new DisplayMessage({type: "error", list: [ "Get All Certificates Error", error.error ]}),
          new Busy(false)
        ]);
      })
    );
  }
```

This returns the error: 'certificate.state.ts(22, 3): The expected type comes from property 'certificate' which is declared here on type 'Partial'

I am new to NGXS and a little lost here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey again! You need to put in more code... or create a stackblitz to share. Basically we need more context. You're fighting simple typescript issues, not NGXS.